# jQuery UI sortable for dynamically added items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have HTML markup where by clicking on an add row button, then a visually hidden HTML element which is sibling to the add new button gets cloned and inserted before it.

```
<div class='wrapper'>
<div class="container">
    <div class="sortable">
        <div class="ui-state-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="sortable">
                    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 1</div>
                    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 2</div>
                    <div class="ui-state-default hidden">Hidden</div> <a href="#" class="add-button"> Add New Sub </a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-state-default hidden">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="sortable">
                    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 1</div>
                    <div class="ui-state-default">Item 2</div>
                    <div class="ui-state-default hidden">Hidden</div> <a href="#" class="add-button"> Add New Sub </a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <a href="#" class="add-button"> Add New </a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is JS code:

```
function sortableInit(container) {
container.find('.sortable').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    cursor: 'move',
    items: '> .ui-state-default',
});
}
$(function () {
$(".container").each(function () {
    sortableInit($(this));
});
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.add-button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var hidden = $(e.target).siblings('.hidden').clone(true).removeClass('hidden');
    hidden.insertBefore($(e.target));
});
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/wpfo0jjw/), giving much closer idea of what I am trying to do.

When you run the jsfiddle, click on the Add New button, for the newly added element, try to sort the element Item 1 and Item 2. Although they can be dragged, but cannot be sorted.

**Note:** The div.ui-state-default element can contain div.container element  upto any depth level(nested repeatable field groups).

Comment: Please post your code in your question and don't try and sidestep the SO rule of doing that when posting a link to jsFiddle. You saw the warning when posting your question, yet you chose to ignore it.

Comment: @j08691 I have updated the question with code.

Comment: I can sort them, so what kind of browser are you using?

Comment: @jiFus I have tried with both chrome and firefox latest versions. Have you clicked on Add New link(not Add New Sub) to add new row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making it more complicated than it needs to be.  Rather than trying to do a deep clone (`.clone(true)`), just call the `sortableInit()` on the cloned item.

## [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/wpfo0jjw/1/)

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', '.add-button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var hidden = $(e.target).siblings('.hidden').clone().removeClass('hidden'); //Removed 'true' from clone
    hidden.insertBefore($(e.target));
    sortableInit(hidden); //This added.
});
```

Comment: Hmmm..by not doing deep clone existing functionality may break. But, I am gonna try this, and refactor existing code if possible.

Comment: @Chetan – You can leave the deep clone if you want.  It's not necessary in your example, but nothing is going to break if it's in there.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work with deep clone. Neither working in example code, nor in actual implementation. But, luckily tried without deep clone on actual implementation, and nothing gets broken. I was already binding events on div.wrapper equivalent and was using event delegation so that was already unnecessary. Btw, does jquery ui sortable destroy existing instance if called on an element that is already initialized?

Comment: @Chetan – No, it doesn't destroy it, but just like anything else make sure you're not overwriting your initial reference with subsequent references.